# How to create a matrix from blocks

Tags: r, matrix, block

I have the following blocks:

```
a = matrix(c(1,3,3,4),nrow=2)
b = c(6,7)
d = 1
```

I expect joint in a matrix, as the following result:

```
> new.matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    6
[2,]    3    4    7
[3,]    6    7    1
```

Comment: `rbind(cbind(a, b), c(b, d))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix `rbind` and `cbind`:

```
rbind(cbind(a, b), c(b, d))
```